# Do I need to set up a DHCP server for a Samba-based Active Directory domain controller?

Tags: active-directory, samba

I'm new to active directory and have been watching some videos to get an idea of the structure. I've also been using VMs in their own virtual network to learn how it all works. I have been using [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Samba/Active_Directory_domain_controller) to set up a domain controller on an Arch Linux server.

Here is a little diagram of the network I've made:

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dEcs.png)

[This video](https://youtu.be/hxgz7MR7MGQ) says that you should let the Active Directory Domain Controller control everything, including DHCP. Does this extend to Samba? If so, how would I do it on Linux?

Comment: If you need a DHCP server, you can use any DHCP server you like. It's not a requirement to use Windows Server DHCP.

Comment: Also, even if you're purely running Windows AD, that thing about the "domain controller should control DHCP" is poor advice in those environments as well. You don't want DHCP on your DCs if you can avoid it.